# Paste multiline text without autoindent in Midnight Commander

Tags: midnight-commander

Using **Midnight Commander**'s built-in `mcedit`, is it possible to paste multiline text without autoindent avoiding going back and force to change **Return Does Autoindent** feature?

Example: I have the following *Perl* code ➤

```
use constants
{
  true   =>  1,
  false  =>  0,
};
```

When I copy it and paste it, I get the following mess ➤

```
use constants
{
  true   =>  1,
    false  =>  0,
    };
```

Is there some convenient way to paste it with preserving its original look?

I am using **SecureCRT** terminal emulator by *VanDyke Software*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the editor, the terminal, and all layers in between (e.g. tmux) support **bracketed paste**.

- mcedit v4.8.31 supports it [since 2013](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/2661) (I tried it).
- SecureCRT v9.5 also supports it [since v8.7.1 (2020)](http://web.archive.org/web/20200513173527/http://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/history.txt) (I tried it), unless [manually disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Q7O.png) in session options.
- (tmux, if you're using that, supports it since v3.1 (2020); GNU Screen supports it since 2015 but still hasn't issued a new release since that day.)

In other words, that works by default unless you're running a much older version or unless you've manually disabled the feature.

To test bracketed paste mode run `printf '\e[?2004h'; cat > /dev/null; printf '\e[?2004l'` and try to paste a small amount of text. You should be seeing `^[[200~the text^[[201~`.

Comment: Unfortunately my SecureCRT license is for v.8.5.3